# how to calculate Hermitian Toeplitz system of equations on fpga in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, dsp, matrix

I'm trying to write vhdl code to solve the Hermitian Toeplitz system of equations (solving for the A's).

```
   [  R(1)   R(2)* ...  R(N)* ] [  A(2)  ]  = [  -R(2)  ]
   [  R(2)   R(1)  ... R(N-1)*] [  A(3)  ]  = [  -R(3)  ]
   [   .        .         .   ] [   .    ]  = [    .    ]
   [ R(N-1) R(N-2) ...  R(2)* ] [  A(N)  ]  = [  -R(N)  ]
   [  R(N)  R(N-1) ...  R(1)  ] [ A(N+1) ]  = [ -R(N+1) ]
```

I know of the levinson-Durbin Algorithm, and the brute force way of inverting the matrix.
Neither of these methods seem to be efficient to implement on an fpga.

What are some other methods that work best for FPGAs? Are there any?

I have done several google searches but nothing useful ever comes up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of the Schur algorithm? It has about the same complexity as Levinson's algorithm but it is said to have better numerical stability. It is described among others in [this paper](http://www.math.niu.edu/~ammar/papers/gsa.pdf). There are also other methods, as described in [this paper](http://genii.bol.ucla.edu/publications/toep.pdf) (and the references therein). I should add that I do not know specifically about how well these algorithms are suited for FPGA implementation, but at least you know some alternatives now.

Comment: I see the methods and they make sense but I don't think they able to be implemented efficiently on an fpga, at least not that I can tell.  Does anyone have experience with doing any of these on an fpga efficiently? My problem is either the design gets incredibly big or it takes a very long time to finish ( >1ms) which is too long.